# Identifying which tab is clicked in accordion panel in JSF Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, tabs, onclick, primefaces, accordion

Is there any way to know which tab from the list is clicked in accordion panel in JSF Primefaces??

I need the property in the bean. 
For eg: I have `lstofItems<Item>` on accordion panel tabs. If i click on one tab, i need a property `Item clickedItem` to be set to that value. I need it to load the data for that tab from DB.

Is there any way ? Maybe using PropertyActionListner or something else. I thought about propertyActionListner but couldn't figure out where to place it. Any suggestion ???

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the example shown in the ShowCase and let us know if it helps: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/accordionPanelChangeListener.jsf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The view:

```
<p:accordionPanel>
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{myBean.onTabChange}" />
    <!-- Define your tabs here -->
</p:accordionPanel>
```

The managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class MyBean {

    public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getTab().getId());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks .. it helped. Although i would prefer using event.getData(); As it return the whole Item. Also the dynamic should be set to "true" in accordion panel . For it to work in my case.

Comment: This link also useful for events : http://www.javabeat.net/primefaces-accordionpanel-ontabchange-ontabshow/